# emacs 27.1 for windows 10 org mode not working during first load (Shell command succeeded with no output)

Tags: emacs, windows-10, org-mode

In Windows 10, Emacs 26.3 with inbuilt org version 9.1.9 is working fine (Packaged binaries). Recently I tried Emacs 27.1. with inbuilt org version 9.3. While loading .org files for first time, I get the message `(Shell command succeeded with no output)` and org files are not rendered at all. To render it, I have to use M-x org-mode or reload the file in the buffer again. I tried to run without loading .emacs.d folder packages. The issue persists. It means, it has nothing to do with already installed other packages. I also tried with latest org version 9.3.7 and and also tried with emacs -Q. Still the issue persists. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Emailed a bug report to  "bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org" after invoking emacs -Q

Comment: I have the same problem... were you able to get this answered?

Comment: I just installed emacs 27 (nov2021), opened an org file, and it was opened as plain text. I had to switch to org mode manually ( M-x org-mode). How can we enable org-mode on startup?

Comment: Try this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71651/12663

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late, but found in Jeffs words:

Evil remaps C-i to evil-jump-forward to emulate Vim’s jump lists feature2, which overwrites the default mapping for the TAB key in Org mode.

To fix the tab key’s functionality in Org mode, sacrifice Evil’s C-i backward jumping by turning it off in your configuration with the evil-want-C-i-jump option.

So to solve, just edit your init.el to look like this:

```
;; Install Evil and disable C-i to jump forward to restore TAB functionality in Org mode.
(use-package evil
         :init (setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil)
         :config (evil-mode))
```

source: https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/emacs-evil-org-tab/